# Javascript inheritance with super() call

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I had some pseudoclasses that shared a large part of their initialization. I decided to take this initialization out and create a base class, from which they'll inherit.

```
function BaseClass(param1, param2) {
    ...
}

function SubClassA(param1) {
    ...
}

function SubClassB(param1) {
    ...
}
```

I want `SubClass1` and `SubClass2` to inherit from `BaseClass` in the following manner:

`SubClassA(param1)` constructor calls `BaseClass(param1, "I am A.")`

`SubClassB(param1)` constructor calls `BaseClass(param1, "I am B.")`

so `BaseClass` adds some properties to them. Then both subclasses do some initialization of their own.

Now I can't just do `SubClassA.prototype = new BaseClass()`, because I want the super constructor to take parameters. How to do this elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function SubClassA(param1) {
    BaseClass.call(this, param1, "I Am A.");
}

function SubClassB(param1) {
    BaseClass.call(this, param1, "I Am B.");
}
```

When you do a `new SubClassA(param1)` or `new SubClassB(param1)` base constructor will be called with appropriate parameters.

Also, there are other ways than `SubClassA.prototype = new BaseClass()` to define base class. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944880/js-confusion-about-inheritance) question for some details. (Disclaimer: The question was asked by me.)

Comment: Ah, call() didn't come to my mind. Ok, thanks ;) @kiswa, if you don't mind, I'll accept taskinoor as he was the first poster :)

Comment: Seems fair to me. But feel free to upvote both! ;) Also, I added a link to MDN for some more details if you're interested.

Comment: Is `param` meant to be `param1`?  Or the other way around?

Answer (score 2):

I made an **Objective-JavaScript helper** called [Class.js](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-js/blob/master/Classes/eppz!kit/Class.js) - https://github.com/eppz/eppz-js - soley for this reason (without any additional boilerplate code to apply, also cut down prototype hassle).

Using it you can easily make this setup as:

```
var BaseClass = Class.extend
({
    param1: null,
    param2: null,

    construct: function(param1, param2)
    {
        this.param1 = param1;
        this.param2 = param2;
    },
});

var SubClassA = BaseClass.extend
({
    construct: function(param1)
    {
        this.super.construct(param1, 'This is A.');
    },
});

var SubClassB = BaseClass.extend
({
    construct: function(param1)
    {
        this.super.construct(param1, 'This is B.');
    },
});

var a = new SubClassA('A stuff.');
var b = new SubClassB('B stuff.');

console.log(a.param1); // A stuff.
console.log(b.param1); // B stuff.

console.log(a.param2); // This is A.
console.log(b.param2); // This is B.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar and I do this:

```
function SubClass (param1) {
    BaseClass.call(this, param1, "I am A.");
}
```

This gives me all the properties of `BaseClass` on the instance object of `SubClass`.

EDIT: Here is some information on [the call function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). It's useful because you can specify what `this` is during the call and provide an argument list.

Answer (score 1):

Add an area method to Rectangle's prototype.Create a Square class that satisfies the following:

1. It is a subclass of Rectangle.
2. It contains a constructor and no other methods.
3. It can use the Rectangle class' area method to print the area of a Square

   ```
   class Rectangle {

     constructor(w, h) {
      this.w = w;
       this.h = h;
     }
   } 
   Rectangle.prototype.area = function()
   {
     var a = this.w * this.h;
     return a;
    }
    class Square extends Rectangle{
        constructor(r) {
           super(r, r)
          }
     }

     const rec = new Rectangle(3, 4);
     const sqr = new Square(3);

     console.log(rec.area());
     console.log(sqr.area());
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of inheritance with super keyword

```
    class Animal {
  constructor(animalName, country) {
    this.animalName = animalName;
    this.country = country;
  }

  update(animalName=null, country=null) {
    if (animalName) {
      this.animalName = animalName;
    }
    if (country) {
      this.country = country;
    }
  }

  show() {
    console.log("A");
    console.log("Animal Name: ", this.animalName);
    console.log("Animal Country: ", this.country);
  }
}

animal = new Animal("Elephant", "India");
animal.show();
animal.update();
animal.show();
animal.update("Dog");
animal.show();
animal.update(null, "Africa");
animal.show();
animal.update("Whale", "Antartica");
animal.show();

class Whale extends Animal {
  constructor(name, animalName, country) {
    super(animalName, country);
    this.name = name;
  }

  updateName(name=null) {
    if (name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
  }

  show() {
    console.log("W");
    super.show();
    console.log("Penguin Name: ", this.name);
  }
}

whale = new Whale("Ele", "Whale", "Goa");
whale.show();
whale.updateName();
whale.show();
whale.updateName("Molly");
whale.show();
whale.updateName(null);
whale.show();
animal.update("Ants");
whale.show();
animal.update(null, "Australia");
whale.show();
animal.update("Mites", "New Zealand");
whale.show();

class Penguin extends Animal {
  constructor(name, animalName, country) {
    super(animalName, country);
    this.name = name;
  }

  updateName(name=null) {
    if (name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
  }

  show() {
    console.log("P");
    super.show();
    console.log("Penguin Name: ", this.name);
  }
}

penguin = new Penguin("Molly", "Penguin", "Goa");
penguin.show();
penguin.updateName();
penguin.show();
penguin.updateName("Pikachu");
penguin.show();
penguin.updateName(null);
penguin.show();
animal.update("Cat");
penguin.show();
animal.update(null, "Russia");
penguin.show();
animal.update("Seal", "Artic");
penguin.show();
```

You can try this code here: https://repl.it/@VinitKhandelwal/inheritance-javascript