# Javascript Prototype Problems

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

My situation is that I am working on a Canvas game using Box2DWeb, so I have a class called *Sprite* that draws an image to the Canvas, I now want to create a *PhysicsSprite* class that inherits methods and properties from *Sprite*.

My *Sprite* class (Sprite.js):

```
Sprite = function (position, dimension, image) {

  this.Position = position;
  this.Dimension = dimension;
  if (image)
    this.Image = image;
  ...

  this.Draw = function (g) {
    ...
  }
  ...
};
```

And I am setting the prototype in *PhysicsSprite* (PhysicsSprite.js) like so:

```
PhysicsSprite = function(position, dimension, world) {

    this.prototype = new Sprite(position, dimension, undefined);
    //alert(this.prototype.Position.X)

    var body = CreateBody();
    this.GetBody = function () { return body; }

    this.Draw = function (g) {
        ...  
    }

    function CreateBody () {
          ...
    }
};
```

Note the **alert(this.prototype.Position.X)**, which does alert me of the position, but if I change the code to **this.Position.X**, I get an error, and similarly, if I have an instance of *PhysicsSprite*, I have to explicitly call the prototype.

This lead me to think that I haven't set the Object's prototype, merely created a property called `prototype`, and set that to a new *Sprite*.

If someone could help me, and explain what I am doing wrong, that would be much appreciated.
I am dyslexic, so I always misspell variables, which is frustrating, so that was the first thing I looked for, but everything looks fine to me.

Comment: You are right. I recommend to have a look at the MDN documentation for examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_constructor_prototype and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited. This question might help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944880/js-confusion-about-inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This lead me to think that I haven't set the Object's prototype, merely created a property called prototype, and set that to a new Sprite.

That's right. Also, you are not making use of the function's prototype at all, since you assign each function directly to the instance (`this.Draw = function() ...`) instead of the prototype.

---

In JavaScript you have something called *constructor functions*. Every function called with the `new` operator is a constructor function.

When a function is called that way (`new SomeFunc()`), a new object is created (lets call it an *isntance*) which inherits from the object referenced by `SomeFunc.prototype` and this instance is available inside that function via `this`.

Now, inheritance basically comes down to having a prototype (`SomeFunc.prototype`) which instead of being an (nearly) empty object (the default), inherits from another function's prototype.

**Example:**

```
function A(name) {
    // `this` refers to a new instance
    // lets set some properties:
    this.name = name;
}

// all "class" methods should be assigned to the prototype
A.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this.name;
};


// lets create a child "class"
function B(name, place) {
    // we have to call the parents constructor with the current instance
    // and the arguments we want to pass on.
    // this is like `super(name)` in Java or `A.__init__(self, name)` in Python 
    // (or `super(B, self).__init__(name)` in Python)
    A.call(this, name);
    this.place = place;
}

// here we connect A's prototype with B's prototype in a way that they
// stay independent 
inherits(B, A);

// B's "class" methods
B.prototype.getPlace = function() {
    return this.place;
};

// now we can do
var b = new B('SomeName', 'SomePlace');
alert(b.getName());
alert(b.getPlace());
```

This is how `inherits` could look like (this implementation is used by the Google Closure library):

```
function inherits(Child, Parent) {
    var Tmp = function() {};
    Tmp.prototype = Parent.prototype;
    Child.prototype = new Tmp();
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
}
```

You see that `Child.prototype` refers to an instance of `Tmp`. But `Tmp`'s prototype is the same as `Parent`'s prototype. That means, the instance returned by `new Tmp()` inherits from `Parent`'s prototype, and since this instance is the prototype of `Child`, all instances of `Child` will inherit from `Parent.prototype` as well.

With ECMAScript 5, this can be simplified to

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

but it's essentially the same. It creates a new object which inherits from `Parent.prototype`.

---

**Further reading:**

- [JS: Confusion about inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944880/js-confusion-about-inheritance)
- [MDN - Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_constructor_prototype)
- [MDN - Inheritance revisited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited)
- [MDN - `new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)
- [MDN - `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [MDN - `.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: Thanks, I implemented your changes, and I understand prototyping a bit more now

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
this.prototype = new Sprite(position, dimension, undefined);
```

to

```
Sprite.apply(this, position, dimension, undefined);
```

You are right, before the change, you are assigning an instance of object to the "prototype" property.

The prototype is a property of the constructor function, not an object instance - i.e. you can access prototype by `PhysicsSprite.prototype`, but not `this.prototype` or `x.prototype` (where `x = new PhysicsSprite()`).

Comment: You cannot assign values to `this`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a very different bird than Java, though they're often mistaken for each other because they both share { and }.  :D

A typical JavaScript class:

```
function Sprite(a,b) {
    // These are per instance
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
Sprite.prototype = {
    // These are per class, all instances share them
    Draw: function (g) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

... and inheritance in JavaScript is very weird.

Comment: *... and inheritance in JavaScript is very weird.* I think that's what the OP needs most help with...