# Inherited child objects share the same array property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

```
> function Parent() {this.arr = [];}
undefined
> function Child() {}
undefined
> Child.prototype = new Parent();
{ arr: [] }
> child1 = new Child();
{}
> child2 = new Child();
{}
> child1.arr.push('From child1');
1
> child2.arr
[ 'From child1' ]
>
```

Given the above, I would expect `child2.arr` to be empty as it is its own object. How can I have child1 and child2 contain their own arr? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to make the assignment in your constructor:

```
function Child() {
  this.arr = this.arr ? this.arr.slice(0) : [];
}
```

That gives each child a copy of the prototype's `.arr` array, if it exists. (It's just a shallow copy, and that's just a possible example.) Assignments to object properties always involve local ("own") properties of the target object, but *references* involve the prototype chain.

Also not that for fairly arcane reasons it's not a good idea to initialize a prototype like that. Better to use `Object.create`:

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
```

That gives you a new object that uses the `Parent` prototype object as its prototype.

[Here is a somewhat old but still interesting question on the topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944880/js-confusion-about-inheritance)

Comment: Adding the assignment in the child constructor works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look into [inheritance in javascript](http://Inheritance%20and%20the%20prototype%20chain)

Basically if the property is not on the object you are looking into javascript looks into it's prototype and tries to find it there until it reaches the `Object`.

Your `Child` does not have property `arr` but it's prototype `new Parent()` does and that one is referred from `Child1` and `Child2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Parent() { this.arr = []; }
function Child() { this.parent = new Parent(); }
Child.prototype = new Parent();
var child1 = new Child();
var child2 = new Child();
child1.parent.arr.push('From child1');
alert(child2.parent.arr);
```